# The issue about the exception which occurs with return statement

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A { 
    A(int id):id_(id){
       std::cout<<"construct A with id: "<<id_<<"\n";
    }
    int id_;
    ~A(){
        std::cout<<"destory   A with id: "<< id_<<"\n";
    }
    A(A const&) = default;
};

struct Y { 
    ~Y() noexcept(false) { 
       std::cout<<"destory Y\n"; 
       throw 0; 
    } 
};

A f() {
  try {
    A a(1);
    Y y;
    A b(2);
    return {3};      // #1
  } catch (...) {
      std::cout<<"handle exception\n";
  }
  A dd(4);
  return {5};        // #2
}
int main(){
   auto t = f();
   std::cout<<"in main\n";
}
```

Its [outcomes](https://godbolt.org/z/cbrfP8) are(GCC and Clang give the same outcome):

```
construct A with id: 1

construct A with id: 2

construct A with id: 3

destory   A with id: 2

destory Y

destory   A with id: 1

handle exception

construct A with id: 4

construct A with id: 5

destory   A with id: 4

in main

destory   A with id: 5
```

Consider this example, It's a variant example from [except.ctor#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/except.ctor#2), I have many doubts to this example and its corresponding note in the standard, that is:

> At #1, the returned object of type A is constructed. Then, the local variable b is destroyed ([stmt.jump]). Next, the local variable y is destroyed, causing stack unwinding, resulting in the destruction of the returned object, followed by the destruction of the local variable a. Finally, the returned object is constructed again at #2.

First, At #1, why create an object of type A? The rule about the `return statement` says:

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from **the operand**.

And the operand of `return statement` is:

> The **expr-or-braced-init-list** of a return statement is called **its operand**.

That means the brace-init-list `{3}` at `#1` is the operand and the result of the call will be copy-initialized by this operand, the last two printed out sentences evidence this opinion.

Well, even if I agree that at `#1` and `#2` will create these temporary objects of type `A`, however I do not agree the order of the destruction of the temporary object and local variable, My point view is what the `return statement` rule says:

[stmt.jump#stmt.return-3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.jump#stmt.return-3)

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, **which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables ([stmt.jump]) of the block enclosing the return statement**.

IIUC, the destruction of these temporaries created by the operand of the `return statement` should be sequenced before these destruction of local variables. So, why the note says "Next, the local variable y is destroyed, causing stack unwinding, resulting in the destruction of the returned object"?   According to the above rule, the destruction of the temporary should occur prior to that of the local variable `y`, and the rule for exception says:

> The destructor is invoked for each automatic object of class type constructed, **but not yet destroyed**, since the try block was entered.

At that point, namely destruction of `y`, the temporary object created by operand of `return statement` has already destroyed, Isn't it?

And the destruction of the object with `id 3` never be evaluated, but this issue has been asked in other SO questions, this issue is not the subject for my question.

I really can't understand this example, How to interpret these asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well, even if I agree that at #1 and #2 will create these temporary objects of type A,

Nothing said anything about "temporary objects" (which is a special term in C++ with a well-defined meaning, which is not applicable here). The return statement initializes the prvalue returned by the function.

If you search for initialization, the first bullet point [[dcl.init]/17 has is](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17):

> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list or is = braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized.

So this instance of copy initialization will immediately be deferred to list initialization. And [list-initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list) here does not need to create any temporaries in order to initialize the prvalue from the given members of the braced-init-list.

So there are no temporaries; there's just the return value object, which is initialized by the braced-init-list through list-initialization.

Comment: Do you mean that this sentence "At #1, the returned object of type A is constructed." where the `returned object` refers to `prvalue result object`?

Comment: @jackX: Um, yes. What else would it refer to?

Comment: Well, I used to consider the `returned object` would be a `temporary object`, that's my wrong reading. However, please look at this [code](https://godbolt.org/z/x45sYj), the destruction for `returned object`(namely, the prvalue result object of the expression `f()`, here is `t` in `main`) still not be destroyed prior to the object `a`, Its behavior is not as the same as what said in the note. how to interpret this?

Comment: @jackX: You know what it means when the text of the standard says one thing, but compilers generate code that does another thing.

Comment: @jackX As it correctly pointed, the result object initialized in #1 is not a temporary object.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer well, the so-called `returned object` refers to `glvalue result` or `prvalue result object` of the function call, in my example, that's the object `t` defined in function `main`, Right?

Comment: @jackX I think "returned object" is an unfortunate wording and "result object" should be said instead.

Comment: @NicolBolas You mean that the compiler does not do this things it should have obeyed the standard?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, I think so. `result object` has well-defined in [stmt.jump#stmt.return-2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.jump#stmt.return-2), instead `returned object` may make misunderstanding(which is this SO question).

Comment: @jackX [This](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/4112) has been just merged. Coincidence? Don't think so.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yup, this is definitely not a coincidence, instead `returned object` is not a good terminology. BTW, what do u think about these [structure wrong](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-discussion/2020/09/0851.php) and [unfortunate wording](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-discussion/2020/09/0849.php)

Comment: @jackX Don't know much about templates. Current instantiation seems a bit broken to me.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, especially the wording "member of primary class template", so many cases would not be covered by such the wording.  About the structure of "transformed type" [temp.func.order#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.func.order#3). If the `If only one of the function templates M...` sentence is considered as the procedure of transforming type, how could one non-static member function be compared with ordinary function(I.E, they would have not the same number corresponding parameters, `P/A`)